# How to prevent the ContentDialog from closing when home key is pressed in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

> Folowing is my code which i am using to prevent losing when back key
>   is pressed, But it is also blocking the "Yes" and "No" buttons of
>   content dialog. What could be the reason?**

```
  dialog = new ContentDialog()
                 {
                    Title = "One basta found",
                            //RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark,
                            //FullSizeDesired = true,
                            MaxWidth = this.ActualWidth // Required for Mobile!
                        };

                        // Setup Content
                        var panel = new StackPanel();

                        panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock
                        {
                            Text = file.Name+" is found. Do you want to add it?",
                            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                        });


                        dialog.Content = panel;                    
                        // Add Buttons
                        dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Yes";
                        dialog.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = true;

dialog.Closing += ContentDialog_Closing;
void ContentDialog_Closing(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosingEventArgs args)
            {            
                    args.Cancel = true;            
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to have open content dialog after back to application from home screen. 
Maybe you should try little workaround. In onNavigatedFrom save information if content dialog is open, and in onNavigatedTo check this and show content dialog again.

Without running visual studio:

```
override OnNavigatedTo(...){
   if(this.contentDialogShouldBeOpen){
      OpenContentDialog();
   }
}

override OnNavigatedFrom(...){
   this.contentDialogShouldBeOpen = isContentDialogOpen;
}
```